# filepicker.io generate title for uploaded photos

Tags: image-uploading, filepicker.io, filepicker

we have developed an application with which we can generate a new album and than upload many photos into it. The generated album is then shown at the page profile

```
filepicker.pickMultiple(
  {
    mimetype: 'image/*',
    maxFiles: 3
  },
  function(Blobs){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(Blobs));
  },
  function(error){
//  console.log(JSON.stringify(error)); - print errors to console
  }

);
```

We are using this, but there is no options to mention the "Title" of the album or photos.

Can anyone help me on this?.